In a bivariate linear regression why is $Y = \alpha X + \beta + U$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants & $U$ is an r.v. an assumption?
Suppose that I want to conduct a bivariate regression between random variables $Y$ and $X$. In the textbooks that I'm reading from, primarily Introductory Econometrics and Estimation and Inference in Econometrics by Jeffrey Wooldridge and Davidson and Mackinnon  respectively, it says we assume that $Y$ and $X$ are linearly related: $Y = \alpha X + \beta + U $ where $\alpha \text{ and } \beta$ are real constants and $U$ is a random variable dubbed the errors or disturbances. I don't quite understand why expressing $Y$ in terms of $X$ like this is necessarily an assumption. It seems that we're always capable of expressing $Y$ in terms of $X$ simply due to arithmetic on random variables.
What I mean by that is this: From a linear-algebraic standpoint, let's consider the set of all real valued random variables defined over a common sample space $S$ and suppose that $Y$ and $X$ belong to $S$. $S$ is a vector space provided that scalar multiplication and vector addition are defined in the standard way, and so it also follows that, for any real  $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have that $\alpha X + \beta$ also belongs to $S$ and that the difference between $Y$ and $\alpha X + \beta$, $Y - \left( \alpha X + \beta \right)$, is in $S$ as well. Call that difference $Y - \left( \alpha X + \beta \right) = U .$ So $Y = \alpha X + \beta + U $. I don't understand where we've really "assumed" anything except that $Y$ and $X$ are random variables defined over a common sample space, but that seems quite trivial. I get that if we specify a criterion such as minimizing the MSE between $Y$ and $\alpha X + \beta$, then we get what $\alpha \text{ and } \beta$ must be. But simply expressing Y linearly in terms of X doesn't seem like much of an assumption. I've heard that the true relationship may not be, and usually isn't, truly linear in the sense that Y = $\alpha X + \beta$ where $U$ is identically zero and I get that. But I don't get how I've assumed anything about the true relationship by merely expressing $Y$ in terms of $X.$ Am I misunderstanding something? I've asked this question elsewhere & people have asserted that the equation $Y = \alpha X + \beta + U$ is an assertion about the relationship between $Y$ and $X$ but I simply don't see how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If $U$ is a random variable with a completely unknown distribution (including unknown mean), and we allow $U$ to depend on $X$, then you're right, we have not actually assumed anything. But almost always we enforce that $U$ has mean 0 and is independent of $X$, thus $Y = \alpha X + \beta + U$ becomes a fairly strict assumption

Makes sense. Thank you.
